# How to set listview in a add() order?

Tags: java, android, listview, retrofit2

How to set listview in a add() order ?
Firstly this is code (not real code)

API_Interface.java

```
public interface API_Interface{
    @GET("/api/{buzz}")
    Call<Buzz> Buzz_API(@Path("buzz") String buzz);
}
```

Buzz.java

```
public class Buzz{ 
    @SerializedName("buzz")
    @Expose
    private String buzz;

    public String getBuzz() {
        return buzz;
    }

    public void setBuzz(String buzz) {
        this.buzz = buzz;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.class

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_main);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        BuzzArrayList<Buzz> buzzArrayList = new BuzzArrayList<Buzz>();
        BuzzAdapter buzzAdapter = new BuzzAdapter(this, 0, buzzArrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(buzzAdapter);

        Retrofit buzz_retro = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://buzz.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

        API_Interface buzz_service = buzz_retro.create(API_Interface.class);

        //Get data
        Call<Buzz> buzz1 = buzz_service.buzz_API("Apple");
        buzz1.enqueue(new Callback<Buzz>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Buzz> call, Response<Buzz> response) {
            String buzz_1 = response.body().getBuzz();    //buzz_1="Apple"
            buzzArrayList.add(new Exchange(buzz_1));
            buzzAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        Call<Buzz> buzz2 = buzz_service.buzz_API("Banana");
        buzz2.enqueue(new Callback<Buzz>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Buzz> call, Response<Buzz> response) {
            String buzz_2 = response.body().getBuzz();    //buzz_2="Banana"
            buzzArrayList.add(new Exchange(buzz_2));
            buzzAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });


        Call<Buzz> buzz3 = buzz_service.buzz_API("Rice");
        buzz3.enqueue(new Callback<Buzz>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Buzz> call, Response<Buzz> response) {
            String buzz_3 = response.body().getBuzz();   //buzz_3="Rice"
            buzzArrayList.add(new Exchange(buzz_3));
            buzzAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
```

I just thought that listview displays in a add() order like this.

```
Apple
Banana
Rice
```

However, in fact, listview displayed like this.

```
Banana
Rice
Apple
```

or

```
Rice
Banana
Apple
```

How do I change my code to display as intended ? I look forward to your response. Thank you.

Comment: call API synchronously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call API synchronously. better to create a function for one API.call concurrently that function

```
    Call<Buzz> buzz1 = buzz_service.buzz_API("Apple");
    buzz1.enqueue(new Callback<Buzz>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Buzz> call, Response<Buzz> response) {
        String buzz_1 = response.body().getBuzz();    //buzz_1="Apple"
        buzzArrayList.add(new Exchange(buzz_1));
        buzzAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Call<Buzz> buzz2 = buzz_service.buzz_API("Banana");
        buzz2.enqueue(new Callback<Buzz>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Buzz> call, Response<Buzz> response) {
            String buzz_2 = response.body().getBuzz();    //buzz_2="Banana"
            buzzArrayList.add(new Exchange(buzz_2));
            buzzAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Call<Buzz> buzz2 = buzz_service.buzz_API("Rice");
            buzz2.enqueue(new Callback<Buzz>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Buzz> call, Response<Buzz> response) {
                String buzz_3 = response.body().getBuzz();    //buzz_3="Rice"
                buzzArrayList.add(new Exchange(buzz_3));
                buzzAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }});
        }});
    }});
```

Comment: Thank you your answer !  but this method is not smart... (if i call many api)

Comment: @NooNoo Yes. it's not smart. call asynchronously is faster. add everything in an ArrayList with an id to differentiate item. then sort accordingly!!!

Answer (score 0):

"Apple", "Banana", "Rice" are added to the list by asynchronous calls,
therefore the order in which they get added is not predictable.
It doesn't matter in what order you wrote the asynchronous `enqueue` calls.

To add the items in a specific order,
it will be best to change `API_Interface` and the Retrofit code to use synchronous method instead of asynchronous.
The syntax is different depending on your version of Retrofit,
follow the examples in the documentation:

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests

Unfortunately, as the documentation points out,
on Android 4.0 or newer the synchronous technique leads to crashes:

> Warning: synchronous requests trigger app crashes on Android 4.0 or newer. You’ll run into the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` error.

Another alternative is to serialize the calls through some other way.
For example you could use a [`Semaphore s = new Semaphore(1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html),
call `s.acquire()` before each `enqueue` call and `s.release()` in each `onResponse` call.

That is:

```
Semaphore s = new Semaphore(1);

s.acquire();
Call<Buzz> buzz1 = buzz_service.buzz_API("Apple");
buzz1.enqueue(new Callback<Buzz>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Buzz> call, Response<Buzz> response) {
        String buzz_1 = response.body().getBuzz();    //buzz_1="Apple"
        buzzArrayList.add(new Exchange(buzz_1));
        buzzAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s.release();
    }
});

s.acquire();
Call<Buzz> buzz2 = buzz_service.buzz_API("Banana");
buzz2.enqueue(new Callback<Buzz>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Buzz> call, Response<Buzz> response) {
        String buzz_2 = response.body().getBuzz();    //buzz_2="Banana"
        buzzArrayList.add(new Exchange(buzz_2));
        buzzAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        s.release();
    }
});

// ...
```

Comment: I am using Retrofit 2. If i use execute() , NetworkOnMainThreadExecption is caused....should i use Asynctask? (Sorry bad english..)